¿Cómo hacer que el color de fondo de un botón en html cambie de color constantemente con CSS?
Quiero hacer que un botón en una página vaya cambiando constantemente el color de fondo para hacer un poco más divertida la página web.
Es para un proyecto de wordle.
#guess-button {
   display: block;
   margin: 0 auto;
   padding: 10px 20px;
   font-size: 18px;
   background-color: #0CBABA;
   color: #fff;
   border: none;
   border-radius: 3px;
 }


Podes dar mas detalles de lo que buscas? cambiar constantemente como? todo el tiempo que oscile entre varios colores? no podemos meternos en tu mente, proporciona mas detalles :) en todo caso en lo que es diseño de interfaces que un boton cambie de color todo el tiempo no es muy atractivo, el color va a depender de la importancia/funcion que tenga ese boton, y la paleta de colores de tu web.

ohhh ok muchas gracias

Por favor, lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Muestra un [repro] de lo que has intentado hasta el momento.

Y por cierto, sugiere a tus compañeros del bootcamp que hagan lo mismo (leer cómo funciona [es.so]), ya que todos están haciendo preguntas relacionadas al miniproyecto de wordle :)

Puedes valerte de la opción de animaciones de CSS3, que se configura con la propiedad animation y sus sub-propiedades en combinación con la regla @keyframes que controla los pasos de una animación.
Por ejemplo, puedes hacer una transición entre dos colores con keyframes from/to y hacer que se repita infinitamente con la sub-propiedad animation-iteration-count
Por ejemplo:


button {
  background-color: red;
  animation-name: ejemplo;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes ejemplo {
  from {background-color: red;}
  to {background-color: yellow;}
}
<button>Botón de ejemplo</button>



También puedes hacer que cicle entre varios colores con keyframes que se van aplicando cuando ha transcurrido una fracción del tiempo de la animación, así:


button {
  background-color: red;
  animation: 3s multicolor;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes multicolor {
    0% {background-color: #000;}
    33% {background-color: #FF0000;}
    66% {background-color: #0000FF;}
    100% {background-color: #FFF;}
}
<button>Botón de ejemplo</button>




muchas graciass

Si esta respuesta realmente te ha sido útil @DiegoBlaich, no olvides aceptarla. Haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.
